# Flutter IOS : CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "simple_permissions":

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, cocoapods, apple-push-notifications

I am new to flutter and developing Permission demo in flutter.
I used **simple_permission** plugin for the same,this plugin works in android but in ios it gives me below error:

> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
>   "simple_permissions":

```
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    simple_permissions (from `.symlinks/plugins/simple_permissions/ios`)

  In Podfile:
    simple_permissions (from `.symlinks/plugins/simple_permissions/ios`)
```

Please help to solve this error!!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Go to your flutter project.
Navigate to ios and open Podfile
Replace the second line of that file with this:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

simple_permissions doesn't work for iOS versions below 10.0